# How can i redirect to an Angular router link with oauth2 login?

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, angular2-routing

I want to make an oauth2 login with Twitch on my website and I have an angular2 website and I'm working with router links.
When I want to log me in with twitch acc to say yes it is me and so everything is fine. Ok the end not xD

When i go to the twitch oauth2 for authorizing i need an redirectUri. My problem is now how can i make this in angular2? Because I can't type www.page.com/app/afterlogin/afterlogin.php or somethink like that.

I need this because I need from the user the access token, I dont want that he need to authorize himself x times.

Maybe this helps for helping me:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[client_id]&redirect_uri=http://www.page.com/app/AfterLogin/afterlogin.php&response_type=code&scope=user_read
```

I hope someone can help me with redirecting and some oauth2 logins :)

Comment: Do you have to use Authorization Code Grant flow?

Comment: it would be better, else i need to save the data from everyone in my own database. And I wanted to make it a bit modern xD

Answer (score 4):

Let me assume a RESTful backend with Single Page Application front and answer the question. The process in general is like the following

Your SPA --> Your Server --> Your Provider --> Your Browser --> Your Provider --> Your Server --> Your SPA

- Your SPA => initializes login and passess `redirect_uri`
- Your Server => Stores `redirect_uri` in a cookie and sends request to
  provider
- Your Provider => Gets Success and Failure Urls and loads login page
  to your browser
- Your Browser => Loads the provider login page
- Your Provider => Sends request to your server success or failure
  handler
- Your Server => Extracts the `redirect_uri` and redirects the browser
  to it
- Your SPA => Gets `afterLoginUrl` from `redirect_uri` and route the
  user to it

Below are the steps to achieve this

1. When your front end sends the authentication request to your server,
   append the `redirect_uri`. In that url, pass a `afterLoginUrl` query
   parameter. That is used by your front end SPA to route the user to
   the specific page that triggered the login. (i.e. If the request has
   been triggered by a user trying to access
   `{base_uri}/profile/project/projects` for example, it is a good
   practice to route the user to this page rather than to the default
   page that a normal login takes to like `base_uri/profile/about`). As
   a result you will have a `url` that looks like the following.

   ```
   `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/oauth2/redirect&afterLoginUrl=/profile/project/projects`
   ```

   port 8080 being for the back end and 4200 for the front end.
2. Since you are using a RESTful service, you don't have a way by which you can save the `redirect_uri` on your server (since REST is stateless). Because of this you need to send it with the request you send to the provider as a cookie.
3. When the success is received from the provider, you will know which route of your SPA to hit by extracting the cookie you sent. Then you dedicate a route to handle your request from your own server (in my case `oauth2/redirect`) in your front end app.
4. On the component specified for the route in step 3 you will receive `token` and `afterLoginUrl`(if there is). You will have something like the following on the url

   `http://localhost:4200/oauth2/redirect?afterLoginUrl=/profile/project/projects&token={token value}`
5. Verify your token, check whether or not there is `afterLoginUrl` and redirect to the route specified by `afterLoginUrl` if there is one or to the default profile page if there isn't.

I think a wonderful resource can be found [here](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Authorization Code Grant flow is just one of several ways of how you can use OAuth2. It's not suited for applications running in a browser, because it requires a client secret which you cannot keep safe in a browser.

There is another flow - Implicit flow which is meant for JavaScript applications - you get an access token and/or ID token in a redirect URI - in the hash part (#...) so they don't get to a server. Then you can easily use any Angular route path as a redirect URI. So the redirect URL from OAuth2 server could look something like this:

```
http://example.com/myAngularApp/afterLogin#token=...
```

When you get to that URI, you just save the token and change the route to some real form.